# Why can't I estimate the Fundamental Matrix from a coplanar set of points?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space, computer-vision

I am learning how to estimate the Fundamental Matrix via the [8-point algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight-point_algorithm):

From N > 8 corresponding points that satisfy $xFx' = 0$, we need to solve the LS problem:

$kron(x,x')f = 0$

Where $kron(x,x')$ is a N by 9 matrix made of the elements of the corresponding points, and $f$ is the matrix $F$ as a column vector.

However, I came a cross a [statement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgGV3l82NTk&t=142s) that if the set of N corresponding points is coplanar, or lying on the same 3D plane, then the LS problem has no solution.

Can someone please explain why the fundamental matrix can't be estimated from a coplanar set of points? Both an algebraic and geometric explanation will be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

In the book, Three-dimensional computer vision by Olivier Faugeras (Page 271) is explained why you can't have coplanar points.

Basically it's because the matrix $kron(x,x^\prime)$ has to be of rank more or equal to 8 to compute the inverse of the eight first columns of $kron(x,x^\prime)$ and recover the essential matrix (as 8x1 vector) as
$$ f=-F_{33}(U_8)^{-1}C_9 $$
Where $U_8$ represent the $n\times8$ matrix formed by the first eight columns of $kron(x,x^\prime)$ and $C_9$ is the ninth colimn vector of $kron(x,x^\prime)$.